# Unable to display second form after successful login validation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to use a progress bar in my windows form application the application validates the login credential on successful completion it displays another form but not able to display it as it has to appear it doesn't display any content and after few moments it gets me back to the original form 
    The cancel button is also not working 
    Plz anyone can give me a solution to this problem

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.Text == "Abrar" && textBox2.Text=="abrar")
    {

        //progressBar1.Visible = true;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 2);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 3);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 4);
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
        Form1 d1 = new Form1();

        d1.Hide();



    }
    if(backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
        return;
    }

}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Cancelled)`enter code here`
    {
        label3.Text = "Cancelled";
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = "Login Successful";
    }
}

private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();


    }
    else if(backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        label3.Text = "Process is running";
    }

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // progressBar1.Visible = false;
}

private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();

    }
}
```

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, no, no. The work you do in the background worker's `DoWork` method is not meant to touch any UI. The very first thing you start doing is accessing control properties. Access that data before starting the background worker and pass the data across to it as *strings*.

Comment: 2.5 questions: Why are you running this with a `BackgroundWorker`? What is `Form1` and why are you immediately hiding it without ever showing it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer...but how should do I do it

Comment: See what i am trying to do is after validating the login details i am trying to display another form that gives a message hello

Comment: And I am just learning to make this simple app a bit responsive by adding a progress bar to it.

Comment: i got the solution i have to do it in this Form2 f = new Form2();
                f.Show();
                Form1 d1 = new Form1();

                d1.Hide();

Comment: In the runworkerCompleted event handler thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.Text == "Abrar" && textBox2.Text=="abrar")
    {

        //progressBar1.Visible = true;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 2);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 3);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 4);



    }
    if(backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
        return;
    }

}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Cancelled)`enter code here`
    {
        label3.Text = "Cancelled";
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = "Login Successful";
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
        Form1 d1 = new Form1();
        d1.Hide();
        this,Hide();
    }
}

private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();


    }
    else if(backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        label3.Text = "Process is running";
    }

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // progressBar1.Visible = false;
}

private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();

    }
}
```